# When POSTing a MultipartEntity using Apache HttpClient, ByteArrayBody works but InputStreamBody throws NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to POST some data taken from an InputStream. I was hoping to avoid having to gather all the data into a byte array first, and instead stream the data, to save memory (I am POSTing data of about 10MB).

If I run the following:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(target_url);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("data", new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[1]), 
    filename));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

then I get:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    [my code starts here]
```

However, if I change one line above, replacing the InputStreamBody with the equivalent ByteArrayBody, then all is well:

```
entity.addPart("data", new ByteArrayBody(new byte[1], filename));
```

What am I doing wrong?

(and would InputStreamBody actually stream the data, or am I wasting my time?)

I am using HttpClient-4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. The issue is likely to be that when using `ByteArrayBody` HttpClient is able to calculate the total request content length and delineates the message using `Content-Length`, while when using `InputStreamBody` HttpClient has to resort to content chunking (using `Transfer-Encoding` header). I suspect the server side script is simply unable to handle requests that do not have a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I guess I'll just stick with `ByteArrayBody`.